# Launching a YouTube iframe player via (outer) javascript on iOS

Tags: ios, api, iframe, youtube, playback

Safari on iOS has a policy that allows playing media only when the current javascript execution begins with a user action, usually a click event.

However when I attach a handler to a button that fires `someYoutubePlayer.playVideo()` and the user **clicks on this button** this is what actually happens:

1. a `click` event is fired in the main page window
2. the `playVideo` method fires a `postMessage` on the youtube `<iframe />`
3. inside the iframe a `message` event is fired
4. handler of the `message` events fires `domVideo.play()` **which will fail, because the current event is no longer `click`, but `message`**, because we are in the inner `iframe` window.

Does anyone know how to overcome this and trigger playing from an outside click event?

Comment: Have you been able to find a workaround by now? This is so frustrating :\

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just load the video from it's url, rather than in an `iFrame`?? This will make the load on your app less and leakage would be at a min.

**e.g.** http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=....